# Azure Cache for Redis Timeout

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I know there are lots of queries on this and I am far from being a redis expert. That said I do see a pattern and was hoping to gain some insight. Our keys are small , maybe around 25 chars. We don't have a huge amount of data per key, 100-400 K. We do get spikes of reads and it appears they start to timeout. They start IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=8188,Min=2,Max=8191) and over a few seconds end up like IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=250,Free=7941,Min=2,Max=8191). Does anyone have any insights as to where we can look to improving this situation. According to the azure portal our memory has peeked around 350mb and even with our spikes server load maxd at 4%. Our cache hits go from < 500 to spiked of 3K / per minute. Any guidance would be great.